# Unable to connect to newly launched EC2 instance using SSH/HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying my hand to learn AWS. I have created an EC2 instance and i am trying to connect to the same using ssh/http. Neither of them seems to work. I have checked the settings of everything that can cause this issue but everything seems to be correct. Please find the screenshots of everything that i have checked.

[image: My Amazon ec2 instance]

[image: Network access control list]

[image: Route Tables]

[image: Security groups]

[image: Subnets]

[image: VPC]

[image: Subnet-2 image]

If you need any other information please let me know because i dont know where i am going wrong.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: click subnet-2 and post the image. Also post what is the error you are getting

Comment: The error that i am getting is that when i try connecting through SSH there is no login prompt that is coming. It gets timed out after some time. Also i just edited my post to give the picture of subnet-2

Comment: add the rule for Port 22 in inbound/outbound traffic for subnet-0231b74f and test for all ips

Comment: Your instance is in Public Subnet 2 which does not have SSH port open on the Network ACL inbound rules. To keep it simple just all all traffic on your ACL and restrict the access to the ports on your security groups. This way other instances in the same subnet can have different ports open to the internet

Comment: Issue resolved?

Comment: Yes Mohan. I recreated the entire configuration from scratch and it started working . Not sure what went wrong the last time.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your NACL to allow SSH traffic inbound.

Comment: Done everything . For all the NACL i have allowed all traffic. Still i dont see the issue resolved.

Comment: For your Security Group Outbound Rules you need to enable all ports. An SSH client will connect (inbound) on port 22 but the reply will be on a random port between ports 1024 and 65535.

Comment: I have enabled all traffic as of now but the response is still the same

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to connect through SSH from Windows OS using putty, try the following,

1. Convert your .pem file to .ppk using puttygen.exe. Load your private key(.pem) and save the private key as .ppk
2. Open putty and point to the converted ppk key under Connections->SSH->Auth [private Key for authentication]
3. Try to connect now using the public DNS. Eg: ec2-user@ as you are using AWS Image.

This should work.

Comment: Did all this . It is the same issue.It not being able to connect. There is no login prompt coming.

Comment: Your EC2 instance is in pubic subnet-2, please have the same configuration[inbound and outbound traffic] as public subnet-1. Currently your public subnet-2 has only traffic allowed for HTTP.

Comment: The given answer is before getting much information from the questionnaire.

Comment: If your internet connection is through a proxy server, may be it is blocking the ssh connection to the ec2 instance.